# How to view a windows winhelp file (.HLP) with wine

Tags: windows, wine

I have wine installed and it works with other windows apps (both under 32bit and 64bit prefixes). I am trying to open a winhelp `*.hlp` file with:

```
wine ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/winhelp.exe file.hlp
```

but I get the following error:

```
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\winhelp.exe"
```

The file at `~/.wine/drive_c/windows/winhelp.exe` is present.

The page at https://wiki.winehq.org/Winhelp indicates that `winhelp [filename.hlp]` should work but does not elaborate on the usage.

Any hints on how to do it?

Comment: You should post an answer to your own question, not edit it with updates.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `winhelp.exe` you should use `winhlp32.exe`.

This should work fine:

```
wine winhlp32 file.hlp
```

If you want to point to a specific `winhlp32.exe` executable under an explicit prefix then you can use the full command:

```
wine ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/winhlp32.exe file.hlp
```

I created a wrapper script in order to avoid typing (writing to `/usr/local/bin` might require `sudo -i` first):

```
echo 'wine winhlp32 "$*"' > /usr/local/bin/winhelp.sh
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/winhelp.sh
```

Now `.hlp` files can be opened with:

```
winhelp.sh file.hlp
```